# looping through dictionary of python data frames issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and ran into a data frame issue. Here it is:

I have 4 dataframes, with all 5 columns categorical:

```
print(dfn4.shape)

print(dfn4_99.shape)

print(dfn4_100.shape)

print(dfn4_1000.shape)
```

---

```
(37524, 5)

(921, 5)

(36603, 5)

(25000, 5)
```

---

I create a dictionary with them:

```
dfl = ['dfn4', 'dfn4_99', 'dfn4_100', 'dfn4_1000']

dfs = {'dfn4':dfn4, 'dfn4_99':dfn4_99, 'dfn4_100':dfn4_100, 'dfn4_1000':dfn4_1000}

for df in dfl:
    print(df, " = ",dfs[df].shape) 

dfn4  =  (37524, 5)

dfn4_99  =  (921, 5)

dfn4_100  =  (36603, 5)

dfn4_1000  =  (25000, 5)
```

then I create dummy variables from categorical ones:

```
 cat_vars=['caller_id'
             ,'u_contact_location'
             ,'category'
             ,'subcategory'
             ,'u_incident_type']
    for df in dfl:
         for var in cat_vars:
            cat_list = pd.get_dummies(dfs[df][var], prefix=var) 
            data2=dfs[df].join(cat_list)
            dfs[df]=data2
```

Then I check again their shape:

```
for df in dfl:
    print(df, " = ",dfs[df].shape) 

dfn4  =  (37524, 2348)

dfn4_99  =  (921, 442)

dfn4_100  =  (36603, 2328)

dfn4_1000  =  (25000, 2002)
```

which is ok. But when I check the shape of one of them it looks unchanged:

```
dfn4.shape

(37524, 5)
```

and yet:

```
dfs['dfn4'].shape

(37524, 2343)
```

why the 2 dataframes are different? I mean `dfn4` and `dfs['dfn4']`

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest that you use back ticks like this: `\`` to make your code bits easier to read. For example: `dfl = ['dfn4', 'dfn4_99', 'dfn4_100', 'dfn4_1000']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs with these lines:

```
data2 = dfs[df].join(cat_list)
dfs[df] = data2
```

[`pd.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) is not an in-place operation (nor is it used as if it were in-place). You are assigning a copy to the variable `data2` and then assigning `data2` to `dfs[df]`.

These operations do not update your original dataframe `dfn4`. If you wish to do so, you will have to do this explicitly. But the entire point of using a dictionary is to avoid explicitly named dataframes. Stick to the dictionary.

If you need take a snapshot of an old version of your collection of dataframes take a deep copy of your dictionary. For example:

```
import copy

dfs = {'dfn4':dfn4, 'dfn4_99':dfn4_99, 'dfn4_100':dfn4_100, 'dfn4_1000':dfn4_1000}
dfs_original = copy.deepcopy(dfs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I fix it.